# Screenshots is not attached Allure + Cucumber + TestNg + EventListener

Tags: event-listener, cucumber-jvm, allure

1. Using Cucumber EventListener, I am trying to capture the screenshots in Allure report, but screenshots is not attached in the report.

Below are my CustomEventListener Code:

```
public class CListener extends TestRunner implements EventListener {

@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
    eventPublisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::stepFinished);
}

private void stepFinished(TestStepFinished event) {
    PickleStepTestStep steps = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
    String stepName = steps.getStep().getText();
    if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("PASSED")) {
        takeScreenshot(webDriver, event.getResult().getStatus().toString(), stepName);
    } else if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("FAILED")) {
        takeScreenshot(webDriver, event.getResult().getStatus().toString(), stepName);
    }
    Allure.addAttachment(stepName, new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
}

private void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String filePath, String screenName) {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("Screenshots\\" + filePath + "\\" + screenName + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

2. Runner Class:

   ```
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"classpath:Login.feature"},
            plugin = {
                      "summary",
                      "pretty", 
                      "io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm","utilities.CListener"},
            glue = {"steps"}
    )
    public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    public static WebDriver webDriver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        if (webDriver != null) {
            webDriver.quit();
            System.out.println("hello: inside teardown");
        }
      }
    }
   ```

[Sample code implementation can be found here](https://github.com/dipakkumar1225/AllureCucumber)

Comment: This is to update that under 'target/allure-results' folder, I observed that screenshot available, but it is not reflected in the report.. Can anyone please help me here..?

Comment: Any help please...